# firebase function returns before finishing the code processing

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this below firebase trigger

```
exports.on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log("start of on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash")   

      const order = snapshot.val();
      const customerObj = order.customer
      const orderObj = order.order

      const paymentType = orderObj._paymentType
      console.log("payment type is::" + paymentType)

      if(paymentType === 'DoodleCash'){
        console.log("payment type is DoodleCash so deduct it from customer account")
        const afterDiscount = orderObj._afterDiscount
        const uid = customerObj._uid

        console.log("Customer uid is::" + uid)
        var db = admin.database();
        const userRef = db.ref('users/')
        userRef.child(uid).once("value").then(
            (resp) => {

                console.log("user value:" + JSON.stringify(resp))
                const userObj = resp.val()
                  let doodleCash = userObj._doodleCash
                  console.log("user current doodle cash is::" + doodleCash)
                  if(doodleCash === undefined)
                     doodleCash = 0

                  if(doodleCash > afterDiscount){
                    const val = doodleCash - afterDiscount

                    console.log("new doodle cash will be:" + val)
                    return userRef.child(uid).update({"_doodleCash" : val})
                  }else{
                        console.error("cannot be a negative value")
                        return null
                    }
            }
        ).catch(
            (err) =>  {
                            console.error("something went wrong:" + err)
                            return null
                     }
            )
      }else{
          return null
      }
})
```

This one of the execution where i can see method finished before the then of userRef.child(uid).once("value") finished.  Why? or how to fix? I believe my code should be blocking and waiting for then to finish before it completes the trigger. Am i missing something here? Please advise

```
2:25:44.698 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
something went wrong:TypeError: Cannot read property '_doodleCash' of null

2:25:44.698 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
user value:null

2:25:36.406 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
Function execution took 618 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

2:25:36.198 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

2:25:35.796 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
Customer uid is::3jwWMscY4mZGATQZg94d7wyRE143

2:25:35.796 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
payment type is DoodleCash so deduct it from customer account

2:25:35.796 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
payment type is::DoodleCash

2:25:35.788 AM
on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash
Function execution started
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you will see in the three official Firebase videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/), for Cloud Functions triggered by events, you **MUST** return a Promise (or a chain of Promises) in your Cloud Function, to indicate to the platform that all the asynchronous work has completed.

If you don't do so, it may happen that the platform stops the execution of your Cloud Function, which is what is apparently happening to you.

So, you should adapt your code as follows:

```
exports.on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("start of on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash")

        const order = snapshot.val();
        const customerObj = order.customer
        const orderObj = order.order

        const paymentType = orderObj._paymentType
        console.log("payment type is::" + paymentType)

        if (paymentType === 'DoodleCash') {
            console.log("payment type is DoodleCash so deduct it from customer account")
            const afterDiscount = orderObj._afterDiscount
            const uid = customerObj._uid

            console.log("Customer uid is::" + uid)
            var db = admin.database();
            const userRef = db.ref('users/')
            return userRef.child(uid).once("value")  // <- Note the return here
            .then(resp => {

                    console.log("user value:" + JSON.stringify(resp))
                    const userObj = resp.val()
                    let doodleCash = userObj._doodleCash
                    console.log("user current doodle cash is::" + doodleCash)
                    if (doodleCash === undefined) {
                        doodleCash = 0
                    }
                    if (doodleCash > afterDiscount) {
                        const val = doodleCash - afterDiscount

                        console.log("new doodle cash will be:" + val)
                        return userRef.child(uid).update({ "_doodleCash": val })
                    } else {
                        console.error("cannot be a negative value")
                        return null
                    }
            })
            .catch(
                (err) => {
                    console.error("something went wrong:" + err)
                    return null
                }
            )
        } else {
            return null
        }
    })
```

Comment: quick question: notice the inner return userRef.child(uid).update({ "_doodleCash": val })  is it good? i have read somewhere that upper the first return that you just suggested make it not to wait for the inner return userRef.chid ... to finish ?

Comment: Yes, it is fine to return a promise within the first `then()`. This is actually the way to chain promises, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining.